# Has a Mapper class to be thread safe

Tags: java, hadoop, thread-safety, mapreduce

To avoid allocating memory at every instance of a Hadoop `Mapper` class and then rely on the GC to clean this memory I use static objects that I access read and write in the `map` method.

Do I have to care about thread-safety ?

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization to me, are you sure you genuinely need multi-threading if you're already using Hadoop to distribute the load of processing?

Comment: I am not trying to use multi-threading. I was afraid hadoop could use threads internally and wondered if it was safe to have an instance of Mapper access some static variable.

Comment: Well, if you're running in distributed mode, these will all be different machines so the static object wont give you any benefit as Enno Shioji says. Even in pseudo-distributed mode, it should be in its own JVM so the same applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, each map task will run on its own JVM. So you won't get any benefit from using a static object. I would recommend not to do something weird unless you actually face performance issues.

Comment: True though Hadoop may reuse the JVM, and `Mapper` object for a next map task. There could be benefit to caching some data across its lifecycle methods then. It also means you have to properly init and clean up each time in lifecycle methods, not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Enno and Quetzalcoatl has said.
As When ever a map task runs in a JVM, it creates a single object of Mapper class, and calls map fn for each input ( i.e. for each row of a file when using TextInputFormat).
But it calls the map fn in sequence and not in parallel. 
So, there should be no problem of Thread Safety of the objects you are using.

Regards,
Manish